# Remove JTable row with String containing ceratin letter

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jtable

Hello I am working on a project with a JTable to join words. In the table words that have been joined together have an @ character between them.

I basically want to remove all the rows in the table containing the character @. This is what I have tried so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
                if ((boolean)table.getValueAt(i, 0).equals("\\b[@]+\\b")) {
                    table.remove(i);
                }
            }
```

This code is not working as intended. I would like to know the correct way to write this code. Thank you for any replies in advance.

Comment: In which way is it not working as inteded ?

Comment: The rows are still there when they should have been removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code calls the [remove() method inherited from the Container class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#remove(java.awt.Component)) - you want to manipulate the table model used by your table.  Assuming that you're using a DefaultTableModel, you can get the model from the table and use the [removeRow() method.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#removeRow(int))

Also, `.equals("\\b[@]+\\b")` doesn't check for a String containing the '@' character.  It checks for an exact match of the text that you specified.  You might want to look at the String.contains(...) method.

Remember that the data in a Swing JTable is [stored in an underlying TableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), not in the JTable object itself.  Something like this should work.

```
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
        if (model.getValueAt(i, 0) != null && model.getValueAt(i, 0).toString().contains("@")) {
            model.removeRow(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The removeRow method gives me an error for some reason

Comment: And how can I use the String.contains(...) method

Comment: undefined for type JTable

Comment: That's because it is on the TableModel, not on JTable itself.  I've added code to my answer above.

Comment: Not used JTable in a long time but is it safe to use `toString()` on a value from the `TableModel`, it could be `null` I believe.

Comment: @AxelH- that's entirely correct.  I've added a null check to make it safer.  I'm not sure what the underlying objects in the OP's JTable are, but if the objects are Strings, a cast to String is probably better than a toString() call anyway.

Comment: I kind of like the `toString` usage in some cases, it is simpler than checking if a cast is possible. But with  `@` it could be a problem since `Object` will print something like : `java.lang.Object@2a139a55`, always true.